# what does tools/test/test-setup.sh test-setup.sh do in bazel

Tags: python, bazel

I'm using Bazel for a Python project.

I profiled a trivial test, which should've taken well below 1s to run, with `bazel test //... --profile=/tmp/profile.gz`. However, the `bazel test` command took over 5s.

The profiling is shown below

[image]

It shows that most of the time it's spent on the action, `action 'Testing //tests/unit/io:test_ds_presto'`, as seen at the **Critical Path** row. Then I find out more details about this action with `bazel aquery`,

```
action 'Testing //tests/unit/io:test_ds_presto'
  Mnemonic: TestRunner
  Target: //tests/unit/io:test_ds_presto
  Configuration: darwin-fastbuild
  ActionKey: 2123d47ebdd54b927b3377c77ce293144693c4e16117fe9d0fdc7b8b7213b392
  Inputs: [bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/internal/_middlemen/tests_Sunit_Sio_Stest_Uds_Upresto-runfiles, external/bazel_tools/tools/test/generate-xml.sh, external/bazel_tools/tools/test/test-setup.sh]
  Outputs: [bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/testlogs/tests/unit/io/test_ds_presto/test.cache_status, bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/testlogs/tests/unit/io/test_ds_presto/test.log]
  Command Line: (exec external/bazel_tools/tools/test/test-setup.sh \
    tests/unit/io/test_ds_presto)
```

so the action is running the command

```
exec external/bazel_tools/tools/test/test-setup.sh tests/unit/io/test_ds_presto
```

Can anyone provide some insight into what the script `tools/test/test-setup.sh` intends to do and why it could possibly take so much time?

I assume the `test-setup.sh` script is this one https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/master/tools/test/test-setup.sh from the bazel repo

**Update**

The profile with `--spawn_strategy=local`, but it's unclear where the time is spent.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`test-setup.sh` is a wrapper around your test target, so you need to ensure that your test is not a problem here. You can use `-s --sandbox_debug` flags to run that script without the Bazel, so it is possible to add some debug calls like `date` inside that wrapper script.
On the other hand time spent in sandboxing routines: `sandbox.createFileSystem` and `sandbox.delete` is pretty high. You can try to run your tests without sandboxing with `--spawn_strategy=standalone` flag

Comment: what does `-s` do as in `-s --sandbox_debug`?

Comment: got it: `--[no]subcommands [-s] (true, pretty_print or false; default: "false")`

Comment: what do you mean by without Bazel if with `-s --sandbox_debug` flags, I'm not totally understanding what `--sandbox_debug` do

Comment: I tried all the suggestion. `-s` is informative and it confirms that the `test-setup.sh` step is slow. What can I do to understand deeper why it's slow. E.g. what's being done in `sandbox.createFileSystem` and `sandbox.delete` that take so much time? Also what's done in `subprocess.run` besides running my test? I wonder if there is a way for me to get into the state right before `test-setup.sh` and then poke the system interactively?

Comment: hmmm, with [`standalone`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/user-manual.html#flag--spawn_strategy), it's much faster, about `2s`, but still much slower than a plain `pytest`, which would only take `0.5s`...

Comment: I added a new screen shot when `--spawn_strategy=local` is used